# How can I insert and fit a PDF file using Latex commands

Tags: pdf, latex, alignment

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height = 3.5\textheight, width = 3.0\textwidth]{fig/InterfaceEMF2ASMFOR}
\end{center}
\caption{list of global parameters customer, FRD versions} \label{fig: limit}
\end{figure}
```

is the code I have used in my Latex file.

NOTE: {fig/InterfaceEMF2ASMFOR} is a pdf file
After the pdf report got generated the included {fig/InterfaceEMF2ASMFOR} does not look good and not fit to the page in PDF report.
The inserted pdf always loose some portion of it and always inserted from the middle of the page but not from the edges of the page.

Please help me how to fit the fig to the PDF I am creating.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the whole pdf page with the `pdfpages` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

test

\includepdf{example-image-a4}

text



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sam for the timely reply.

Comment: unfortunately I am not allowed to use pdfpackages.. Could you please explain me a way how to do with the /includegraphics instead.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use pdfpages?

Comment: unfortunately i am not sure about that. What all i am trying to do is just fit the pdf file i have with \includegraphics but cannot adjust it to the full page

Comment: So if you don't have a reason not to use it, you should use pdfpages. It internally uses `\includegraphics` to insert the image and does all the adjustments for you.